# close form for stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am new to stochastic calculus. Can I know how to compute the close-form solution for 
$$\int_0^t \exp(\alpha s - \sigma W_s) \; ds$$
and
$$\int_0^t \exp(\alpha s - \sigma W_s) \; dW_s.$$
I encounter that when trying to solve for the following SDE
$$dX_t = \theta(\mu - X_t)\; dt + \sigma X_t \; dW_t$$

Comment: If the SDE is written correctly, that is not an [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein–Uhlenbeck_process) and your integrals don't seem to match it either. An O-U process has additive noise (i.e., diffusion function is not a function of the state variable) while the SDE as written has multiplicative noise. Also, an O-U process definitely does have a known analytical solution (see Doob, Ann. Math. 43, 1942).

Comment: @n.c. Your comment isn't accurate unfortunately. As "horchler" pointed out, the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process does NOT have multiplicative noise, unlike the process posted in this question. To appropriately solve this SDE, consider applying Ito's Lemma on $Y_t = ln(X_t)$

Answer (score 9):

**Another Solution**

We should look for a solution of the form
$$X(t)=U(t)V(t)$$ 
where
$$dU_t=-\theta\,U_tdt+\sigma\,U_t\,dW_t$$
and
$$dV_t=\alpha(t)dt+\beta(t)dW_t$$
$U$ is a geometric Brownian motion, therefore 
$$U(t)=U(0)\,e^{-(\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t}$$
let $U(0)=1$, this yields $V(0)=X(0)$. Now we should find $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$. 
$$dX_t=U_tdV_t+V_tdU_t+d[U,V](t)$$
we have
$$dX_t=(\alpha (t)U_t-\theta\,X_t+\sigma\beta(t)U_t)dt+(\beta(t)U_t+\sigma\,X_t)dW_t$$
thus $\beta(t)=0$ and $\alpha(t)U_t=\mu\,\theta$, as a result
$$dV_t=\frac{\mu\theta}{U_t}dt$$
in the other words
$$V_t=V_0+\mu\theta\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{U_s}ds$$
finally
$$X_t=U_tV_t=e^{-(\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t}\left(X(0)+\mu\theta\int_{0}^{t}e^{(\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)s-\sigma W_s}\right)$$
$$X_t=e^{-(\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t}+\mu\theta\int_{0}^{t}e^{-(\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(t-s)+\sigma (W_t-W_s)}ds$$

Answer (score 7):

To solve this equation, let 
\begin{align*}
M_t = e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t - \sigma W_t}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
dM_t = M_t\Big[\big(\theta +\sigma^2\big) dt - \sigma dW_t\Big].
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
d(M_t X_t) &= M_t dX_t + X_t dM_t + d\langle M, X \rangle_t\\
&=\theta\,\mu\, M_t dt.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
M_t X_t &= X_0 + \theta\,\mu\,\int_0^t M_s ds.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
X_t &= X_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t + \sigma W_t} +  \theta\,\mu\,e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t + \sigma W_t}\int_0^t e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) s - \sigma W_s} ds\\
&=X_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t + \sigma W_t} +  \theta\,\mu\,\int_0^t e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) (t-s) + \sigma(W_t - W_s)} ds.
\end{align*}

Comment: Fine solution +1