# Expected payoff at future time

Tags: options, option-pricing, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, itos-lemma

Let  $a$, $b$, $c$, and $e$ be constants, $W_1$ and $W_2$ be Brownian motions with correlation $\rho$, and $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ be deterministic functions of time. Let $X$ satisfy $$d(X(t))=(aX(t)+ef(t)g(t))dt+f(t)X(t)dW_1(t)+g(t)X(t)dW_2(t).$$ Compute the expected value of $X(T)^2$ given $X(t)$ for some $0\le t\le T$.

If $e=0$, we can use Ito's rule to write $d(\log X)$ as an expression independent of $X$. Integrating gives that $X(T)|X(t)$ is log-normal.  If $e\neq 0$, $d(\log X)$ is no longer independent of $X$. I can't think of a way around this issue.

Comment: Where does $c$ come in? Just use Ito's lemma on $X(t)^2$ and integrate.

Comment: $b$ and $c$ are irrelevant. $d(X(t)^2)$ depends on $X(t)$. You have to compute $\mathbb{E}(X(T)^2)$ given $X(t)$ for one value of $t$.

Comment: Then where does $b$ and $c$ come from? I think your question is missing a critical piece. You'll see why if you just use Ito's lemma on $X(t)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on ideas from [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8478/close-form-for-stochastic-integral/25988#25988), let
\begin{align*}
M_t = e^{-at+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t (f^2+g^2+2\rho fg)ds -\int_0^t(f dW_1(s)+gdW_2(s))}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
dM_t = M_t\Big[\big(-a + f^2+g^2 + 2\rho fg \big)dt - f dW_1(t)- gdW_2(t)\Big].
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
d(M_tX_t) &= M_t dX_t + X_t dM_t + d\langle M, X\rangle_t\\
&=e M_t f g dt.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
X_T = \frac{M_t}{M_T}X_t + e\int_t^T\frac{M_s}{M_T} f(s)g(s)ds.
\end{align*}
Now, you should be able to compute the conditional expectation.