# How to estimate parameters for 2 correlated Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes with maximum likelihood?

Tags: programming, mean-reversion, multivariate, parameter-estimation

I would like to use maximum likelihood to estimate the parameters of two correlated Ornstein-Uhlenbeck [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) from empirical data.

Do you have any good references for this? If you have any hints as to how to code it in Matlab, that would also be great.

I suppose I can just use the log-likelihood function for multivariate processes and then I need mean and variance of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, e.g. as described in this [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/4932/467). Right?

However, even once I have coded it in Matlab, I would still have to reference where I got the formulas from, and there it would be helpful to have some (academic) papers.

I am familiar with the [paper](https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~jes9/bio/Short-term_Long-term_Model.pdf) by Schwartz and Smith 2000 (Short-term variations and long-term dynamics in commodity prices, Management Science), but this one is on 1 O-U and 1 Brownian Motion.

Comment: Could you please give us the multivariate SDE that you want to estimate. Otherwise it is not clear if you want two 1D O-U with correlated Brownians or a proper 2D O-U process.

Comment: The Brownians are correlated with $dW_1 dW_2 = \rho dt$. The two O-U processes are $dX_1 = k_1 (\mu_1-X_1)dt + \sigma_1 dW_1$ and $dX_2 = k_2 (\mu_2-X_2)dt + \sigma_2 dW_2$ .     I managed to solve it with a multivariate log-likelihood and the help of getting the covariance of the two processes (from [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25526/what-is-the-covariance-of-two-correlated-ornstein-uhlenbeck-processes/25536?noredirect=1#comment36287_25536)).

Comment: The only problem that remains is that $k_1$ and $k_2$ are consistently over-estimated, which is a common problem to which I didn't find any solution in the literature. I am wondering whether I should use least squares instead of likelihood...

Comment: Since the model is Gaussian MLE and OLS are equivalent. If the true $k$ is close to zero then you have a have a 'unit root' problem and the sampling distribution of the parameter is Dickey-Fuller rather than Student-t. This is skewed, therefore it is known and expected that you are more likely to overestimate.

Comment: Ah... this makes sense... And do you know of any ways to apply correction terms? I found ways to do reduce the fat right tail, e.g. the jackknife-technique described [here](https://commoditymodels.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/estimating-the-parameters-of-a-mean-reverting-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process1.pdf). But the variance of the estimate always stays more or less the same and since I only have one set of data, I would need to reduce the variance...

Comment: What about estimating the parameters of a VAR(1) model for a bivariate time series? Since Vasicek model is equivalent to AR(1) in discrete time, I think this should work. Please, correct if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what exactly you want but have a look at the article [Calibrating the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (Vasicek) model](https://www.sitmo.com/?p=134).

You calibrate the first one in stand alone, then the second one in stand alone, finally you can compute correlation on the residuals of the increments knowing your parameters.

Comment: This would assume that the proccesses are independent, though. Yet they are correlated so I for sure have to use the multivariate log-likelihood approach. I already found the expected value and variance of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. Now I am still trying to figure out how to get the covariance of two O-U processes.

Comment: I think you do not understand my answer. Do the mean reversion and volatility parameter of one process depends on the other ?